# How to get CheckBox working with ItemTemplate

Tags: asp.net

I need to get CheckBox working with my GridView, so it displays whether the checkbox read from the database is checked or not.

SArchive - the checkbox field - is a Bit field in the database.

IF DBNull I want no tick in the CheckBox.  Unfortunately at the moment it's showing either true or false text next to the checkbox.  When I edit the record that has a true, the check box is not checked, even though it's true in the database.

Screenshot: Not edited

[image]

Screenshot: Edited mode

[image]

code:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SArchive") %>' >
    </asp:CheckBox>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="cb1" runat="server" 
                  Text='<%# Eval("SArchive") == DBNull.Value ? false : Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("SArchive"))%>'>
    </asp:CheckBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Any help please, thanks.
Tea.

Comment: You need to set the `Checked` attribute with your code, not `Text`.

Comment: Now giving me a 'Specified cast is not valid.' when binding the GridView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the `Checked` property:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="Label7" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("SArchive") == DBNull.Value ? false : Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("SArchive")) %>' >
```

Comment: Now giving me a 'Specified cast is not valid.' when binding the GridView.

Comment: It's happening when it's reading Null from the database.  So my DBNull check isn't working, any idea?  Thx

Comment: Do you need to evaluate "SArchive" in the true case of your ternary? Can you just return true?

Comment: In my database I've existing records that have null in SArchive, so I need to check for it (that's whats giving the error).  Do you know how, and how to make checked false if it is dbnull?

Comment: My fault, sorry, I need sleep! :D  I was editing the wrong checkbox.  All working now.  Thanks.